# Replace all hyphens before the first bracket within a file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use sed or perl to replace all hyphens which occur in a file before the first instance of );

So far I have the following which replaces all hyphens in my file but I can't get it to only match upto the first instance of ");".

```
perl -pi -e 's/[^.*);]?-/_/' 00-90.sql
```

Further information:

I'm trying to remove the invalid hyphens from create table SQL which has been generated, we have 1k+ files to get through but anything I hit it with replaces all hyphens.

Example of text to be cleansed:

```
CREATE TABLE e_00_90 (
Last_Name nvarchar(50),
  Initials nvarchar(3),
  Company_Division nvarchar(50),
  Status nvarchar(12),
  Ckeyword5 nvarchar(15),
  Value_of_Contract_-_Overh decimal(20,2)
);
insert into export_00_90 values ('Sample-One', 'R', 'Div 1', 'Expired', 'ANONYTR', 5000);
insert into export_00_90 values ('Sample Two', 'R', 'Div_2', 'Expired', 'WISHBONE', 13000);
```

I only need the Create Table block to have hyphens removed.

Comment: Try `'s/^((?:(?!\);).)*)-\);/$1_);/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[EDIT]*
With awk:

```
awk -v RS=');' -v ORS=');' '/^CREATE TABLE/{gsub("-","_")}1'
```

With perl:

```
perl -pe'BEGIN{$/=");"} /^CREATE TABLE/&&y/-/_/'
```

With sed:

```
sed '/^CREATE TABLE/{:;/);/!{N;b};y/-/_/;}'
```

The awk and perl ways are the same, they use a record separator `);`, check if this one starts with "CREATE TABLE" and translate each hyphen to an underscore.

The sed version isn't very different except that you need to build the text block yourself, appending each line until the `);`. *(Note that this way assumes that there no more code after the `);` in the same line)*:

```php
{
  :  # define an empty label
  /);/! # if ); doesn't match
  {
    N # append a newline to the pattern space
    b # go to the label
  }
  y/-/_/ # translate
}
```

---

*[OLD ANSWER: only works by line]*
With sed:

```
sed -E ':;s/^(([^)-]|\)[^;-])*\)*)-/\1_/;t'
```

or with perl:

```
perl -pe's/.*?\);|.+/$&=~y|-|_|r/e'
```

*(This way matches all until the first `);` or the end of the string, then each hyphen in the match is translated to an underscore using `y///`)*

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know you could use `t` command without a label.

Comment: @SLePort: in fact, you need a label, but this one has an empty name.

Comment: Thanks.  Both of these appear to translate all hyphens into underscores, even those after the first instance of );.

Comment: @uint32: I answered to the first version of your question, the one without a multiline example. So my answer and others are designed to work by line. Now your question is totally different.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte:  Thanks for your input.  Apologies that my initial questions wasn't as clear as it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:(?!PAT).)*` is to `PAT` as `[^CHAR]` is to `CHAR`, so

```
s/\G (?: (?! \); | - ) . )* \K - /_/xsg
```

Alternative:

```
s/\G (?: (?! \); ) [^-] )* \K - /_/xg
```

Fastest:

```
s/\G (?: [^)-]++ | \)(?!;) )* \K - /_/xg
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^)]*)-([^)]*\);)/\1_\2/;ta;'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try and tackle it with a magic regex, but rather:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   if ( m/CREATE TABLE/ .. /\);/ ) { 
      s/-/_/g;
   }
   print;
}


__DATA__
CREATE TABLE e_00_90 (
Last_Name nvarchar(50),
  Initials nvarchar(3),
  Company_Division nvarchar(50),
  Status nvarchar(12),
  Ckeyword5 nvarchar(15),
  Value_of_Contract_-_Overh decimal(20,2)
);
insert into export_00_90 values ('Sample-One', 'R', 'Div 1', 'Expired', 'ANONYTR', 5000);
insert into export_00_90 values ('Sample Two', 'R', 'Div_2', 'Expired', 'WISHBONE', 13000);
```

The range operator lets you test if you're between two delimiters, and only apply the expression there.

As a one liner, this would be:

```
perl -pi -e 'm/CREATE TABLE/ .. /\);/ && s/-/_/g' 00-90.sql
```